# how to read a file and load an object on application startup spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having `Yaml` file that contains configuration for example navigation items, names for plugins, etc,. currently I am reading this file in component class and have to inject it in every class, is there any way that I can read and load this .yml file on application startup make it available application wide and create html file without injecting in every class and calling it in every method ?

this is how i am reading file.

```
List<Manifest> readManifestYamlFiles(String path) {
        // adding the files content to the list
        List<Manifest> manifestFiles = []
        // variable to hold the fileContents
        String fileContents = ""
        // recursively looping over the plugins directory to read the manifest.yml file
        println path
        new File(path).eachDirRecurse() { dir ->
            // looking for only .yml file
            dir.eachFileMatch(~/.*.yml/) { file ->
                // set the fileContent to the variable
                fileContents = new File(file.getPath()).text
                // map manifest.yml file content
                Manifest manifest = yamlUtility.mapYamlToObject(fileContents, Manifest.class, new Manifest())
                // add content of each file to the list
                manifestFiles.add(manifest);
            }
        }
        return manifestFiles
    }
```

Comment: quite unclear what is your problem. The text speaks of one yml file, the code parses several yml file into a list of Manifest. "and have to inject it in every class": What needs to be injected? The list?

Comment: Consider to load the yml files by using spring mechanisme into the spring Environment. Then inject only the Environment into the classes which can then read each property they want.

Comment: @Heri - I am having multiple yaml files that's what returning list, I want to have this list throughout my application.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like ideal use case for [`@ConfigurationProperties`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties)